# R replace values in array with half of the non-zero values in the same columns

Tags: r, replace

I am trying to replace values in columns of an array with half of the non-zero values in the same columns. For instance:

```
# example    
a <- c(0, 1, 3)
b <- c(2, NA, 4)
c <- cbind(a,b)
# find non-zero minimum and divide by 2    
m <- apply(c, 2, function(x) min(x[x>0], na.rm = T))/2
```

I'd like to get this

```
     a   b
[1,] 0.5 2
[2,] 1   1
[3,] 3   4
```

but when I try to replace 0 (and NAs) with the values calculated above using:

```
cc <- apply(c, 2, function(x) replace(x, x==0, m))
```

I get the message that NAs are not allowed and that the number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. I understand what the problem is, but can't figure out how to solve it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
apply(c, 2, function(x) "[<-"(x, !x | is.na(x), min(x[x > 0], na.rm = TRUE) / 2))

#        a b
# [1,] 0.5 2
# [2,] 1.0 1
# [3,] 3.0 4
```

BTW: Please don't use `c` for the name of an object since it's already the name of a very basic R function.